# IndexOutOfBoundException on method called in a JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to retreive a number of istances of the class Flat from the file Flat.ser and with this aim I wrote the method here reported:

**Flat.java**

```
public static ArrayList<Flat> retreiveFlat() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("path/Flat.ser");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Flat f;
    ArrayList<Flat> al = new ArrayList<Flat>();

    while (fis.available() > 0) {
        Object retrieved = ois.readObject();
        if(retrieved instanceof Flat) {
            f = (Flat) retrieved;
            if(f.getTypeOfFlat().equals("Double")) {
                al.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    ois.close();
    return al;
}
```

The method is used in a jsp page:

**Page.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="Entity.Flat" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%
    ArrayList<Flat> al = new ArrayList<Flat>();
    al = Flat.retreiveFlat();
    int i = 0;
    while(al.get(i) != null){
      //do something   
    i++;}%>
```

The problem is that the istance of al is empty in the jsp page though I have assigned it with the return of the method retreiveFlat() and though in debug mode I see that inside the body of retreiveFlat() method the list is not empty. So I get the exception of type IndexOutOfBoundsException when I call the get() method on al. 
Anyone could tell me where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the list is empty, but your attempt to iterate over the list will indeed throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You should use a for-each loop (also called [enhanced for](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)).

Replace

```
while(al.get(i) != null){
    // do something with al.get(i)
i++;}
```

with this:

```
for(Flat flat : al) {
    // do something with flat
}
```